# Why I have two arguments when i call my method?

Tags: python, arguments, self

I wrote a program which work but without using self and now i try to rewrite it with "self".
I put some self pretty much everywhere but i have a problem of given argument.
First i create a class:

```
class photo():
    def _init_cam(self,x,y):
        self.camera = PiCamera()
        self.camera.resolution = (x,y)
        self.camera.start_preview()
        sleep(2)
        print("camera init")
        return self.camera
```

The method which give me problems :

```
def capture_image(self):
        global wait # Empeche le if de ce déclencher avant la fin de la fonction
        wait = False 
        # Get the current date as the timestamp to generate unique file names.
        self.date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y_%H.%M.%S')
        # Add date as timestamp on the generated files.
        #camera.annotate_text = date
        # Capture an image as the thumbnail.
        self.camera.capture('/home/pi/Pictures/' + self.date + '.jpg')
        print("\r\nImage Captured! \r\n")
        wait = True
```

In my main I create my object :

```
camera =photo()
camera._init_cam(3280,2464)
```

Then I call my method :

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(23,GPIO.FALLING,callback = camera.capture_image, bouncetime = 300)
```

The error :
TypeError: capture_image() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I have no idea why it gives a second argument and if there is any way to see what is this argument.

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably `GPIO` passes an argument to the callback when calling it…?

Comment: Thanks, it seems it gives me channel number.

Answer (score 1):

As per the example in the Threaded Callbacks section [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/), the callback is passed a parameter that they've named `channel`. Documentation for that library seems sparse though so I can't tell you what the parameter means.

Comment: Yeah that's it. Thanks.